# FastAI library v1 with Google Colab

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory, fast-ai

I am trying to install the FastAi library and use it with Google Colab. I am

Using:

```
!pip3 install fastai
!apt-get -qq install -y libsm6 libxext6 && pip install -q -U opencv-python
import cv2
from os import path
from wheel.pep425tags import get_abbr_impl, get_impl_ver, get_abi_tag
platform = '{}{}-{}'.format(get_abbr_impl(), get_impl_ver(), get_abi_tag())
accelerator = 'cu80' if path.exists('/opt/bin/nvidia-smi') else 'cpu'
!pip install -q http://download.pytorch.org/whl/{accelerator}/torch-0.3.0.post4-{platform}-linux_x86_64.whl torchvision
import torch
!pip install Pillow==4.1.1
!pip install image
%matplotlib inline
```

imports/ installs everything, 
but when I run

```
from fastai.imports import *
```

The last line gives an error that reads:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'as_tensor'

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong/why it is not importing fastai library when it is the first thing installed?

The full error I receive is as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-9f9378ae0f2a> in <module>()
----> 1 from fastai.imports import *

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/fastai/__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from .basic_train import *
  2 from .callback import *
  3 from .callbacks import *
  4 from .core import *
  5 from .data import *

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/fastai/basic_train.py in <module>()
  1 "Provides basic training and validation with `Learner`"
----> 2 from .torch_core import *
  3 from .data import *
  4 from .callback import *
  5 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/fastai/torch_core.py in <module>()
  1 "Utility functions to help deal with tensors"
----> 2 from .imports.torch import *
  3 from .core import *
  4 
  5 AffineMatrix = Tensor

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/fastai/imports/__init__.py in 
<module>()
  1 from .core import *
----> 2 from .torch import *

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/fastai/imports/torch.py in <module>()
  1 import torch, torch.nn.functional as F
  2 from torch import ByteTensor, DoubleTensor, FloatTensor, HalfTensor, 
LongTensor, ShortTensor, Tensor
----> 3 from torch import nn, optim, as_tensor, tensor
  4 from torch.utils.data import BatchSampler, DataLoader, Dataset, Sampler, 
TensorDataset

ImportError: cannot import name 'as_tensor'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using previous version of torch `torch-0.3.0.post4` which didn't have `as_tensor`.

So you can use other version of torch like `torch-0.4.1` which have this method.

After running following snippet:

```
!pip3 install fastai
!apt-get -qq install -y libsm6 libxext6 && pip install -q -U opencv-python
import cv2
from os import path
from wheel.pep425tags import get_abbr_impl, get_impl_ver, get_abi_tag
platform = '{}{}-{}'.format(get_abbr_impl(), get_impl_ver(), get_abi_tag())
accelerator = 'cu80' if path.exists('/opt/bin/nvidia-smi') else 'cpu'
# !pip install -q http://download.pytorch.org/whl/{accelerator}/torch-0.3.0.post4-{platform}-linux_x86_64.whl torchvision
!pip3 install http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-0.4.1-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl

import torch
!pip install Pillow==4.1.1
!pip install image
%matplotlib inline
```

You can use :

```
from fastai.imports import *
```

Comment: This answer doesnt include pip install fastai in the answer, but otherwise works. Thanks!

Comment: @JoeS oh. I made mistake while copying. added it.

Answer (score 2):

```
from os import path
from wheel.pep425tags import get_abbr_impl, get_impl_ver, get_abi_tag
platform = '{}{}-{}'.format(get_abbr_impl(), get_impl_ver(), get_abi_tag())
accelerator = 'cu80' if path.exists('/opt/bin/nvidia-smi') else 'cpu'
!pip3 install torch_nightly -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/{accelerator}/torch_nightly.html


import torch
print(torch.__version__)
print(torch.cuda.is_available())
print(torch.backends.cudnn.enabled)
```

If this part is okay, as of today you should see the following output:

```
1.0.0.dev20181019
True
True
```

Then move on to installing the latest release of fastai:

```
!pip3 install fastai
```

and test with:

```
from fastai.imports import *
```

Answer (score 1):

I was missing dependencies. I have made an awkward workaround that installs the previous version of the library (with dependancies), then uninstalls the library and replaces it with the updated version.

Code as follows.

```
!pip install "fastai==0.7.0"
!pip uninstall "fastai==0.7.0"
!pip install fastai 
!apt-get -qq install -y libsm6 libxext6 && pip install -q -U opencv-python
import cv2
from os import path
from wheel.pep425tags import get_abbr_impl, get_impl_ver, get_abi_tag
platform = '{}{}-{}'.format(get_abbr_impl(), get_impl_ver(), get_abi_tag())
!apt update && apt install -y libsm6 libxext6

accelerator = 'cu80' if path.exists('/opt/bin/nvidia-smi') else 'cpu'

!pip install -q http://download.pytorch.org/whl/{accelerator}/torch-0.3.0.post4- 
{platform}-linux_x86_64.whl torchvision
import torch
!pip install Pillow==4.1.1
!pip install image

%matplotlib inline
from fastai.imports import *
```

Comment: Doesn't fastai v1 require pytorch 1.0 ?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment Google Colab comes with FastAi and you don't need to install it separately. You can start using it right away and import modules like this

```
from fastai.vision import *
from fastai.metrics import *
```